# Toggle one list item instead of entire list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a card that lists radio stations and when you click on a station a picture drops down for that list item. all data i am pulling from a json.

I have tried building the list in the `toggle.js` and in the `app.js` files

app.js-- `div` with toggle (its all inside a card..many divs)

```
           <div class="card-trip-infos">
              <div>
               <Toggle />
              </div>
              <img class="card-trip-user avatar-bordered"/>
            </div>
```

toggle.js render block:

```
    state = {
        on: false,
    }
    toggle = () => {
      this.setState({
      on: !this.state.on
      })
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <ul>
              <div>
                  <p>{PostData.radios[0].name}</p>
                  {PostData.radios.map((postDetail, index) => {
                    return <div>
                    <li onClick={this.toggle}>
                      <span id='radioName'>{postDetail.name}</span> <span id='frequency'>{postDetail.frequency}</span>

                    </li>
                    {
                      this.state.on &&  <img src='imagesrc'></img>
                    }


                    </div>
                  })}
              </div>

          </ul>
        )
      }
    }
```

I dont know what exactly is wrong but i expect to be able to toggle a picture for each list row seperately. i am confused where to iterate over my json and where to plug everything in.

many Thanks!!

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: You not toggling the data right you getting the data based on selection in the list, right?

Comment: @Neil I believe i do want to toggle the data. But i also want to get the data based on selection.. Lets say i click on the first list item, i want to to get (toggle) the picture just for the first list item. right now if i click on the first list item, i get the picture for every list item (every list item toggles and under it is the picture).

Comment: What state does toggle have? Can you please show the toggle function 

Comment: @Neil i just edited the main post for you, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component for individual list item, have a state there which will hold a boolean property to tell whether the image is to be shown or not. Render function will look something like this:

```js
render (
  return (
    <li onClick="this.toggleShowImage()">
      <div> {props.data.name} </div>
      <div> {props.data.frequency} </div>
      {this.state.showImage ? <img src='imageUrl' /> : null }
     </li>
  )
)
```

Then in toggle.js iterate through your data and create the list components. The render function will look something like below:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
       {PostData.radios.map((postDetail, index) => {
          return <ListItem key={postDetail.name} data={postDetail} />
       })}
    
    </ul>
   )
}
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but will i have to change my state function? i added it in with the render function in my main post. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @derric-d You don't need to change that function. In my solution just replace the function "toggleShowImage" with your "toggle" function and it will work. Also, replace the property name "showImage"( that I have used) with "on" (which you are using).

Comment: What is this ListItem element? I get an error saying it is undefined. also do i put the first render block you wrote in App.js? or its own component? Thanks!

Comment: nvm i see where you said component above :P thanks fr the reply!

Comment: @derric-d Welcome :) Can you please accept my answer if it helped solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't know your toggle function and all your component we can't make exact suggestions but in order to do what you want here (just toggle the selected item), you have two different approaches.

1. You can keep the selected state in the component itself.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cards: [
      { id: 1, name: "foo" },
      { id: 2, name: "bar" },
      { id: 3, name: "baz" }
    ],
  };

  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {cards.map(card => (
          <Card
            key={card.id}
            card={card}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: false
  };

  handleSelect = () =>
    this.setState(state => ({
      selected: !state.selected
    }));

  render() {
    const { card } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={this.state.selected ? "selected" : ""}
        onClick={this.handleSelect}
      >
        {card.id}-{card.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

2. You can keep the selected state in the parent component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cards: [
      { id: 1, name: "foo" },
      { id: 2, name: "bar" },
      { id: 3, name: "baz" }
    ],
    selected: {}
  };

  handleSelect = id =>
    this.setState(state => ({
      selected: { ...state.selected, [id]: !state.selected[id] }
    }));

  render() {
    const { cards, selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {cards.map(card => (
          <Card
            key={card.id}
            card={card}
            handleSelect={this.handleSelect}
            selected={selected[card.id]}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Card = ({ card, handleSelect, selected }) => {
  const handleClick = () => handleSelect(card.id);
  return (
    <div className={selected ? "selected" : ""} onClick={handleClick}>
      {card.id}-{card.name}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: hey, i added the state function to my main post. But thanks for the answer! I wasnt aware i could use the state like that.. ill look into your current solution further.

Comment: I like this but I would consider moving selected to the card state, since both state properties are tied to the same index. Also card should be spreaded `card.name` makes no sense..

Comment: @derric-d, map your items separately and then keep a state each of them as I do here. So, you can manage the toggled state of each item. Otherwise, your toggle state is affecting all your items I suppose. @Neil, keeping the state in the parent sometimes can be useful. Not for this example maybe but there are some use cases. This is why I provided both solutions :) I don't understand the `card.name` spread part? By the way, thanks for the `key` suggestion that I forgot :)

Comment: No worries  I think there is another key above also.. the spread comment was because a card prop is unneeded you are already in the context of a card, if you spend then you can destructure our `name` and `id` easily.

Comment: A note on the state comment you made. Personally I would map over the data and add a ternary expression to update/change the selected property otherwise just return the current item in array. This will keep the order as expected.

Comment: The second key is added :) I would personally want to see your example. I am curious about it :)

Comment: I dont follow @devserkan.. In your state function it says card.. where does that come from and why do i need it? and where do you get the id and name inside it? what should i do with that? im confused as to why thats necessary. I just want a list in a card, not a card for each list item..sorry if this sounds stupid but i have no idea what that state function is supposed to do??

Comment: @devserkan should i take all the json data and put it in card? is it like a constructor? i thought to have the cards built in the app.js and then iterate over my json data made sense but now i have no idea at all what im doing

Comment: @devserkan, i also dont get the significant difference between your first and second solution.. whats the selected bit do?

Comment: @derric-d, my answer is just an example. You don't need anything about `cards` of course. I'm giving you just the idea here. At the end of the day, you have a list (like `cards`) and you want to map and render them somehow. So, use my answer as an example and manage your `on` state as I do with my `selected` state. For example, you can create a `Post` component and instead of rendering `div` and `li` elements directly, you can move those in your `Post` component and keep an `on` state there. This is similar to my first example.

Comment: @devserkan thanks that actually clears up a lot of questions I had! Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: The difference is, in the first example you move the state logic to the component itself but in the second one you keep the state in the parent and the child component is a dumb one. You can pick either of them according to your use case. For example, think about that, what if you need to know how many of the items are selected? In this case, keeping your state in the parent would be suitable. For your question, if you need an exact solution you can put a minimal working app to [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io). You are welcome by the way.